# looping through multiple pages with selenium

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

am running the following code to scrape a  website.

```
import selenium
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import time
import pandas  as pd
from selenium import webdriver as wb
time.sleep(2)
driver=wb.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.jumia.co.ke/')
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="jm"]/div[4]/section/button').click();
move=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="jm"]/div[3]/button').click(); 
time.sleep(3)
clickObj=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//* 
[@id="jm"]/main/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/a[5]/span')
clickObj.click()
```

I want to loop thru all the pages within  the following code

```
  little=driver.find_elements_by_class_name('name')
```

I've tried looping thru it using the following code but it just returns the first
elements in the 1st page

```
desktop=[]
condition=True
while condition:
little=driver.find_elements_by_class_name('name')
for you in little:
    i=you.text.strip()
    desktop.append(i)
try:
    dabb= driver.find_element_by_xpath(' //* 
  [@id="jm"]/main/div[2]/div[3]/section/div[2]/a[7]').click()
    
except:
    condition=False
```

how can I loop thru all the pages?

Comment: Have you verified the value that gets assigned to little and that its more than just one item?

Comment: yeah. I checked out using len and it returns 48 for the 1st page. total items are 304

Comment: Seems that you exit on first iteration. If your try/catch fail to find your element you exist your while loop.